# Uploaded files via FTP to my server not working

Tags: upload, filezilla

I use Filezilla to upload new images to my Magento site. Then I empty the cache, refresh my page and see the changes. So far so good. Then after a few minutes I refresh the same page again and gone are the changes I uploaded before. The older version images are now shown What is going on?

I changed the FTP client, refreshed the cache of my browsers before and after and so on; nothing helps. I still can't get newer files to replace the old ones on my sites.

Someone have an idea what's wrong here?

Comment: Did you try another browser to see if it's a site issue vs. your browser cache?

Comment: Is the file upload actually successful? What does FileZilla tell you in the log?

Answer (score 0):

From the information you provided, it looks to me like you are having a caching problem. Try emptying the browser cache or using a different browser to see if this is actually the problem.